# Count Files Inside NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have a NSIS executable files and I just want to list the numbers of files inside each of the files.

Is there any way on how to determine the count of files inside the setup.exe or NSIS files without extracting it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NSIS itself does not support this.

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) is able to understand most NSIS installers and you can use their command line tool to get a file listing.